# Microsoft Graph ItemNotFound error when trying to get a workbook from sharepoint

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I followed this tutorial: https://mihai-albert.com/2020/05/13/using-microsoft-graph-to-modify-excel-files-stored-in-sharepoint-online-with-c/

When I use graph-explorer and do a
GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')?select=name,id,webUrl](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root/search(q=%27%7Bsearch-text%7D%27)?select=name,id,webUrl)
then I get the item id with no problem.
But then when I want to get the workbook in my application

```
 private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        public GraphService(
           IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureAdOptions)
        {
            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                   .Create(azureAdOptions.Value.ClientId)
                   .WithTenantId(azureAdOptions.Value.TenantId)
                   .WithClientSecret(azureAdOptions.Value.ClientSecret)
                   .Build();

            var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        }

        public async Task Test()
        {
            try {
                var range = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[{drive-id}].Items[{item-id}]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
               

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

then I get an itemnotfound error despite putting in the correct id's.
It can find the drive if I just add that part, so it doesn't seem like there's a problem with my setup.
has anyone encountered this problem or knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using application permissions to call *GET /drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}*, your app needs one of the application permissions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) most likely **Files.Read.All**

I have observed that when you have an **acess_token** that does not have one of the required permissions, you get **itemNotFound** which is misleading.

In your case just add **Files.Read.All** application permissions(requires admin consent) to your app on Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually eventually figured it out, but forgot to update this post.
The error was indeed misleading.